# Successively filling in a new column of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I would like to extend an existing pandas DataFrame and fill the new column successively:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'col2': [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]})
df['col3'] = pd.Series(['a' for x in df[:3]])
df['col3'] = pd.Series(['b' for x in df[3:4]])
df['col3'] = pd.Series(['c' for x in df[4:]])
```

I would expect a result as follows:

```
  col1 col2 col3
0   1   7   a
1   2   8   a
2   3   9   a
3   4   10  b
4   5   11  c
5   6   12  c
```

However, my code fails and I get:

```
  col1 col2 col3
0   1   7   a
1   2   8   a
2   3   9   NaN
3   4   10  NaN
4   5   11  NaN
5   6   12  NaN
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Why do you use `['a' for x in df[:3]]` and not just `['a' for x in range(3)]`? I mean the `x` variable in this list comprehension is not useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`loc` accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html?highlight=loc#pandas.DataFrame.loc):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'col2': [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]})
df.loc[:2,'col3'] = 'a'
df.loc[3,'col3'] = 'b'
df.loc[4:,'col3'] = 'c'
df
```

|  | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 7 | a |
| 1 | 2 | 8 | a |
| 2 | 3 | 9 | a |
| 3 | 4 | 10 | b |
| 4 | 5 | 11 | c |
| 5 | 6 | 12 | c |

Answer (score 2):

As @Amirhossein Kiani and @Emma notes in the comments, you're never using `df` itself to assign values, so there is no need to slice it. Since you can assign a list to a DataFrame column, the following suffices:

```
df['col3'] = ['a'] * 3 + ['b'] + ['c'] * (len(df) - 4)
```

You can also use `numpy.select` to assign values. The idea is to create a list of boolean Serieses for certain index ranges and select values accordingly. For example, if index is less than 3, select 'a', if index is between 3 and 4, select 'b', etc.

```
import numpy as np    
df['col3'] = np.select([df.index<3, df.index.to_series().between(3, 4, inclusive='left')], ['a','b'], 'c')
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2 col3 
0     1     7    a 
1     2     8    a
2     3     9    a
3     4    10    b
4     5    11    c
5     6    12    c
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you do something like `df['col3'] = pd.Series(['a' for x in df[:3]])`, you're assigning a **new** `pd.Series` to the column `col3`. One alternative way to do this is to create your new column separately, then assign it to the `df`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'col2': [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]})
new_col = ['a' for _ in range(3)] + ['b'] + ['c' for _ in range(4, len(df))]
df['col3'] = pd.Series(new_col)
```

Comment: `['a' for _ in range(3)]` can be `['a'] * 3`.  since you are not using the looped index.